# C++ underline output

Tags: c++, underline

How can I underline a text which is supposed to be an output of a c++ code?

Somewhere in the web I saw this:

```
cout<<underline<<"This is the text which is going to be underlined.";
```

But, for me this "underline" is not working. Any idea is very welcome.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with standard C++, possibly with a UI framework like QT

Comment: There is no way in standard C++ to do this, Google 'ncurses'.

Comment: If you go on yahoo answer the best answer starts like so: " I hope you're not expecting something simple, like this: 

`cout << underline << "this text should be underlined";` "

Comment: Not a standard it is!

Answer (score 10):

Are you outputting to an ANSI terminal? If so, the following escape sequence should work:

```
#define underline "\033[4m"
```

[More information on ANSI escape sequences is available here.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html)

Note: To turn underlining off again, use `"\033[24m"`.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest and most portable method is just this:

```
cout << "This is the text which is going to be underlined." << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the best answer. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The following is an extensive example written for G++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
    char normal[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3','9','m',0};
    char black[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3','0','m',0};
    char red[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3','1','m',0};
    char green[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3', '2','m',0};
    char yellow[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3', '3', 'm',0};
    char blue[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3','4','m',0};
    char Upurple[]={0x1b,'[','4',';','3','5','m',0};
    char cyan[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3','6','m',0};
    char lgray[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3','7','m',0};
    char dgray[]={0x1b,'[','0',';','3','8','m',0};
    char Bred[]={0x1b,'[','1',';','3','1','m',0};
    //for bold colors, just change the 0 after the [ to a 1
    //for underlined colors, just change the 0 after the [ to a 4
    cout<<"This text is "<<black<<"Black "<<red<<"Red ";
    cout<<green<<"Green "<<yellow<<"Yellow "<<blue<<"Blue\n";
    cout<<Upurple<<"Underlined Purple "<<cyan<<"Cyan ";
    cout<<lgray<<"Light Gray "<<dgray<<"Dark Gray ";
    cout<<Bred<<"and Bold Red."<<normal<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete Paul R answer, I sometimes create this function in my consol programs:

```
std::string underline(const std::string &s) {
    return std::string(s.length(), '-');
}
```

Then you can do:

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto TEXT = "I am underlined";
    std::cout << TEXT << std::endl << underline(TEXT) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

other possibilities:

```
void underlineAndDisplay(const std::string &s);
std::string underlineWith(const std::string &s, char c);
```

Well, let's go back to my code...